Using setFragmentResultListener in activity
My container activity handles navigation in some cases like this:
fun navigate(directions: NavDirections, extras: Navigator.Extras? = null) {
            extras?.let { navController.navigate(directions, extras) }
                ?: navController.navigate(directions)
    }

one of the fragments returns some data with:
setFragmentResult("request code", bundleOf())

I would like to get that result in the activity but
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityHomeBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        supportFragmentManager.setFragmentResultListener("reqeust code", this) { _, _ ->
            //do something
        }
}

doesn't work.
I'm sure the problem is not fragment-side as the same code is used to pass data to other fragments
Any way to do this?

I guess the problem is that you are setting the fragment result in a different fragment manager and not in the support fragment manager
Can you show more code?
Is setFragmentResult("request code", bundleOf()) called like this parentFragmentManager.setFragmentResult("request code", bundleOf()?
Try, requireActivity().supportFragmentManager.setFragmentResult(...)
If that works then my guess is correct.

ah I see, you're right. but I'm pretty sure that will make the other cases where that fragments send data back not work anymore. how can I find the correct fragment manager to set the listener on?

I guess you have to figure out what fragment manager they are all using. Or maybe you can make them all use the supportFragmentManager of the activity.

Maybe debugging can help you figure out what fragment manager they are using.
